# Perl split the string and print separator too

Tags: perl, split

I have a string and splitting with respect to colon(:) or semicolon(;) followed by space.

Here is code snippet.

```
my $string = "MAJOR RCB_Board: Circuit Disconnected";

my ($rest, $text) = split(/;|:\s+/, $string);
print "Rest=$rest ** Text=$text\n";
```

But here I want to print split separator also with the string. In this example (`:`).

So I should get output like below:

```
Rest=MAJOR RCB_Board: ** Text=Circuit Disconnected
```

Comment: You can put the regex in parenthesis to return the separators, see [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: Also note that `\s+` is only present in the right hand side alternative, you probably meant `/[;:]\s+/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch (part) of the separator by putting it into parentheses.

e.g. :

```
my $string = "MAJOR RCB_Board: Circuit Disconnected";

my ($rest, $separator, $text) = split(/(;|:)\s+/, $string);
print "Rest=$rest$separator ** Text=$text\n";
```

Comment: `my $string = "MAJOR RCB_Board: Circuit Disconnected: what";` how we do if the third split comes `: what` in this?

Comment: If we want we can add ,2 as a third parameter to split, so $text will be 'Circuit Disconnected: what'. For more details, you can look up https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/perldoc-html/functions/split.html